# customizing slide layouts in slidify

Tags: slidify

I am interested in using different layouts for different slides within my index.Rmd file. after copying the template provided [here](http://ramnathv.github.com/slidify/customize.html) and below, I created a .html file in my `assets/layouts` folder.

```
<slide class="{{ class }}" id="{{ id }}">
  <hgroup>
    {{{ header }}}
  </hgroup>
  <article>
    <hr noshade size=4 color='red'>  
    {{{ content }}}  
    <div class='left' style='float:left;width:48%'>
     {{{ left }}}
    </div>    
    <div class='right' style='float:right;width:48%'>
     {{{ right }}}
    </div>
  </article>
</slide>
```

having got this far, it remains unclear:

1) why the slides in my deck are blank and not displaying any of the below:

```
---
#testing
hello

*** left

- point a
- point b
- point c

*** right

- point a
- point b
- point c
```

---

2) how to "call" the custom layout from my assets folder for **an individual slide** and not the whole deck

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify a layout for a slide as metadata. For example, if you saved the layout you describe in the question as `twocol.html` in `assets/layouts`, then you can specify the layout in the slide level metadata. A `&` specifies a layout, while a `.` specifies a class and a `#` specifies an id. You are also free to define your own custom metadata as `key:value` pairs.

```
--- &twocol

## Two Columns

*** left

- point a
- point b
- point c

*** right

- point a
- point b
- point c
```