# Slidify: can't get layouts to work

Tags: layout, slidify

I'm new to Slidify and I'm trying to create my first layout and get it to work properly. I started with the two columns layout that is also shown as an example on the Slidify website.

Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. I created an `twocol.html` file in the `assets/layouts` folder with the content shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259455/customizing-slide-layouts-in-slidify) for instance. Then I simply made the slide like the best answer user did there. I.e. I started it with `--- &twocol`, and I specified `*** left` and `*** right` sections.

*Problem #1*: if I do it like this it doesn't work at all. The slide I get <strike>is empty</strike> only has a red line in it, no text whatsoever.

I can solve problem #1 by adding

```
---
layout: slide
---
```

to the beginning of the `twocol.html` file.

Then I have

*Problem #2*: a slide appears, the title is shown, so is a red line below it, but the contents are not shown at all. I also get an extra slide that is totally empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem too until I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932773/slidify-alignment-of-codes). Now my twocol.html is working and looks like:

```
---
layout: slide
---
{{{ slide.content }}}
<div style='float:left;width:48%;'>
  {{{ slide.left.html }}}
</div>
<div style='float:right;width:48%;'>
  {{{ slide.right.html }}}
</div>
```

Also be sure to add  the equal sign before left and right: `*** =left` `*** =right`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. My solution was like this:

```
--- &twocol

# Two Columns
Some text


*** =left

- text1


*** =right

- text2

---
```